# problem when I load a page using django, Page not found (404) Request Method: GET

Tags: python, django

I followed a tutorial from YouTube about django but I face a problem when I create a page and I try to load it. The server seems to run normal but when I load the page which I created I get the following error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/playground/hello
Using the URLconf defined in storefront.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, playground/hello, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

here is the code for settings.py file

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-_ko=j(tbb+7&m^e-_ti8upt9d6nt#bxl_4&2*tk-co5s!gph+h'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'playground'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'storefront.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'storefront.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

here is the code for views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def say_hello(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World')
```

here is the code for urls.py file for playground page

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns= [
    path('hello/', views.say_hello)
]
```

here is the code for urls.py file for storefront page

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('playground/', include('playground.urls'))
]
```

Comment: try once with `/` http://127.0.0.1:8000/playground/hello/
though it is a get reqiest so it shouldn't matter but try

Comment: You are missing a trialing slash try this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/playground/hello/`

Comment: I tried with a trailing slash but Iget the same error

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have `playground` folder and in it `urls.py` file in your django project? From this I can only see that your application name is `storefront` with `urls.py` file. So make sure you are including existing url config.

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs):

> Whenever Django encounters include(), it chops off whatever part of the URL matched up to that point and sends the remaining string to the included URLconf for further processing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue if you or anyone is looking for an answer to this issue it's very simple you have to save the changes before executing, in VS code we tend to forget to do so. Once you do that it works like a charm also fyi once you get it working most likely you will lose the default home page which is quite normal and you don't have to freak out.

Answer (score 0):

im also followed youtube totarial and i encountered this same problem the reason in i didn't saved all the files after i saved all the files (ctrl+s) then refreshed the browser its worked properly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).